# Is there a way to show a list of snippets available for a particular language?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd love to see a list of all of my snippets installed so that I can see what snippets are available to me to help with discoverability.

Is there a way to do this? Some magic command pallet command or 3rd party extension that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an `Insert Snippet` command that lists all snippets available for the current document's language. Here's an example with some built-in snippets for JavaScript:

[image]